# Merging unversioned files with GIT

Tags: git, merge

I'm working on a project and a co-worker modified some files that I modified too, the problem is that I was versioning using GIT and he was not, so the files modified by this person were never commited to the project repository, he just sent them by email.

Is there a way to merge these files using a GIT merge tool?

Comment: Is your coworker using another version control system? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a new branch locally on your machine from a commit before you made changes to the same files
2. Copy the other person's files into your working directory
3. Commit the changes to the new branch
4. Merge the two branches like normal

Comment: I'm curious to know if the OP's coworker is using some other version control system, like SVN or TFS. Both people could use Git and just push and pull to and from each other's machines directly, and then check things in to their version control system.

Comment: From the question it seemed that they were emailing changes.  So not using version control at all.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to merge if only one side ever had the files. Just add them to the branch of your choice

```
 git add file1 file2 file3
```

and commit

```
 git commit -m 'merged the missing files'
```